# Query about htaccess and preventing access to a directory

Tags: apache-http-server, htaccess

I have developed a website which has a structure that can be summarised as:

```
 htdocs
     .htaccess
     ...
     wp-content
      ...
      uploads
       ...
       Private
        .htaccess
        ...
```

I need to access files in the Private directory from a Members Only within the website, but protect them from direct access.  For example, if I enter the following in a web browser I can access a document directly:

```
http://www.Mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/Private/Admin-Accounts.xls
```

I thought this could be solved by including the following in the `Private/.htaccess` file:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

However, it doesn't seem to matter what is in the `Private/.htaccess` file, I can still directly access files in the Private directory.  The contents of the `.htaccess` file in the root directory seem to over-rule.

If I search the site I find `.htaccess` files in numerous directories.  What defines which one is in use?

Answer (score 0):

> I thought this could be solved by including the following in the `Private/.htaccess` file:
>
> ```
> order deny,allow
> deny from all
> ```

Yes, ordinarily that would be all that's required to prevent direct access to the `Private` subdirectory and all files within. (Except that `Order`/`Deny` directives are deprecated and you should be using the corresponding `Require` directives instead on Apache 2.4 - but that is a side issue.)

> The contents of the `.htaccess` file in the root directory seem to over-rule.

Possible, but unlikely. Generally, the `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory overrides the parent.

We would need to see the contents of the root `.htaccess` file to debug this further.

However, it is possible that `.htaccess` overrides have not been enabled for this subdirectory (or specifically, only enabled for the root) in the server config. The processing of `.htaccess` files is not the default behaviour. This must first be explicitly enabled in the server config for the directories in question using the `AllowOverride` directive. Although, normally, enabling `.htaccess` overrides for the document-root directory will  enable `.htaccess` overrides for the entire subdirectory tree.

> What defines which one is in use?

Providing `.htaccess` overrides are enabled for the requested directory tree (as mentioned above) then all `.htaccess` files along the particular filesystem path are processed. Generally, this is in the order: parent directory to child directory, so that directives in the child `.htaccess` file override the parent. But note that this can vary by module.